# データフレームの複数列を一つの列で割る

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

以下のようなデータフレーム

```
a1,a2,a3,b1
1,1,2,4
3,4,2,1
3,6,2,9
...
```

を考えます。
c1=a1/b1,c2=a2/b1,c3=a3/b1をそれぞれ計算してデータフレームの右につけようと考えています。
この場合は3変数なのでまだ手で書けますが、（Rの場合は`mutate(c1=a1/b1,c2=a2/b1,c3=a3/b1)`でしょうか。)より変数が増えたときに対応できる方法をPython(pandas), R(dplyr)の両方で知りたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

pandasならこうでしょうか。

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4],
                    [3,4,2,1],
                    [3,6,2,9]],
                  columns=["a1","a2","a3","b1"])

df2 = df1.div(df1["b1"], axis=0).drop("b1", axis=1) # 各列をb1で割る
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda s: s.replace("a", "c"))

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) # 右に連結
```

Rで同様にやるならこうでしょうか。

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a1=c(1,3,3), a2=c(1,4,6), a3=c(2,2,2), b1=c(4,1,9))

df2 <- df1 / df1$b1
df2$b1 <- NULL
df2 <- rename_all(df2, function (x) sub("a", "c", x))

df3 <- cbind(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず書いてみました。
こんな感じでどうでしょうか。

**Python版**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':[1,3,3],'a2':[1,4,6],'a3':[2,2,2],'b1':[4,1,9]})

df.join(df.loc[:, :'a3'].div(df['b1'], axis=0).add_prefix('d_'))
#   a1  a2  a3  b1      d_a1      d_a2      d_a3
#0   1   1   2   4  0.250000  0.250000  0.500000
#1   3   4   2   1  3.000000  4.000000  2.000000
#2   3   6   2   9  0.333333  0.666667  0.222222
```

**R(dplyr)版**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a1=c(1,3,3), a2=c(1,4,6), a3=c(2,2,2), b1=c(4,1,9))

df %>% mutate(d=df[1:ncol(df)-1] / df$b1)
#  a1 a2 a3 b1      d.a1      d.a2      d.a3
#1  1  1  2  4 0.2500000 0.2500000 0.5000000
#2  3  4  2  1 3.0000000 4.0000000 2.0000000
#3  3  6  2  9 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.2222222
```